# Redirect built-in functions to wrapped class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to make a wrapper class that behaves in exactly the same way as the wrapped object (with a few specific exceptions). The problem I'm having at the moment is with built-in functions. How could I redirect built-in functions to the wrapped object?

```
class Wrapper:
    def __init__(self, wrapped):
        object.__setattr__(self, '_wrapped', wrapped)
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(object.__getattribute__(self, '_wrapped'), name)

class Foo:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
    def __abs__(self):
        return abs(self.val)

foo = Wrapper(Foo(-1))
print(foo.val) # Okay
print(abs(foo)) # TypeError: bad operand type for abs(): 'Wrapper'
```

Comment: `Wrapper` should have `__abs__` defined. The simplest would probably be to inherit from `Foo`. This can be done dynamically with metaclasses.

Comment: If you want to track changes to objects, you only need to wrap mutables. Numbers are not mutable, so you don't need to wrap those.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I know, it's just a toy example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can dynamically create a new class that is subclass of both `Wrapper` and `Foo`, so you'll have all the properties needed:

```
class Wrapper:
    def __new__(self, wrapped):
        cls = type(wrapped)
        new_type = type(cls.__name__ + '_wrapped', (Wrapper, cls), {})
        return object.__new__(new_type)

    def __init__(self, wrapped):
        self._wrapped = wrapped
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self._wrapped, name)
```

So now you can do:

```
>>> foo = Wrapper(Foo(-1))
>>> abs(foo)
1
>>> type(foo)
<class '__main__.Foo_wrapped'>
```

PS:

- You don't need `object.__getattr__` (or `__setattr__`) in the `__init__` and `__getattr__` functions to get and set this attribute.
- You may want to cache this operation to avoid creating a new class at every new object.

Comment: I suppose the order of the parents is important. `Wrapped` should be first so that its `__getattr__` method has greater priority.

Comment: @PaulManta Yes. Thats what the `(Wrapper, cls)` tuple does. It sets `Wrapper` as first parent